# Como puedo imprimir varias cosas con un solo print en python?

Tags: python

Ejemplo,yo tengo esta linea de codigo
diccionario={"angel":17,"karla":18,"chepe":18}

Lo que quiero saber es como con un solo print me pueda dar el resultado de las 3 edades 17,18,18

Comment: `print(f"{diccionario['angel']}, {diccionario['karla']}, {diccionario['chepe']}")`

Comment: Tal vez te sirva [esto](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#fancier-output-formatting)

Comment: `print(", ".join(map(str,diccionario.values()))`

Comment: `print(*diccionario.values(), sep=",")`

Answer (score 0):

puedes llamar el metodo  *values* que te retornara el valor de cada clave
de la siguiente manera

```
datos={"angel":17,"karla":18,"chepe":18}#diccionario

edad=datos.values()#funcion para devolver las edades
print(edad)#imprime el valor  de la claves
```

Comment: Y si en vez de saber el número quiero saber texto ?       datos=[{"nombre":"angel","edad":"12","sexo":"hombre"},{"nombre":"paola","edad":"14","sexo":"mujer"}]
    Digamos que tengo esa linea de codigo y quiero saber los nombres en un solo print